# MVC project: How to add Seed method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using the standard MVC template which comes with VS 2013.  I have Enabled-Migrations.  I am also able to add additional tables to `ApplicationDbContext`.

How do I add a Seed method to insert some sample rows to my tables, without disrupting the migration process?

Can I insert some rows in one of the migration `Up` methods?  If so, how do I access `ApplicationDbContext` without hardcoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Configuration.cs file that was created under the Migrations folder, you can override the Seed method.  The seed method will be called when you run `Update-Database`.

[More information at asp.net](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3)